# Kdenlive rendering never stops

Tags: kdenlive

When I render in Kdenlive it just says rendering remaining 0 secs but it never completes. I'm using the Version 18.08.3 and Linux Mint 19 64-bit with kernel4.15.0-42-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 19:32:57 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the main reason for the error, but try unchecking "paralell processing" under "more options" before rendering.

[image]